# Prestashop Shipping Module based on Driving Distance

Tags: php, prestashop

I am coding a shipping module for prestahop which will display the map and then driving distance is calculated based on miles or km returned. But I don't know how to implement that in a module.

I know I should extend module with `CarrierModule` but I dont know which will display map and other things. If someone guide me with the initial step.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems no prestashop developer is willing to help. I wrote the module myself. Here is the [Link](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/262141-shipping-module-based-on-driving-distance/page__pid__1306296) if someone wants to use it, it has bugs, you are free to modify code.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use the google map API.
In your template, create a div called "gmap"for example, then use the example code given in the API documentation to setup your map.

So you have to use the API throught a javascript file, in your hook you can use : $this->context->controller->addJS( link to your js file )

About the distance, I guess your have your different points in a database, you can use this kind of query :

```
$formula = "(6366*acos(cos(radians...";

$sql = 'select *, ' . $formula . ' AS DISTANCE FROM ' . $yourTableName . ' ORDER BY DISTANCE LIMIT 20';
```

So now you have your delivery points, simply use markers from google map API to display it on the map.

Then to display the itinerary, the google map API has everything to do it.

Good luck :D .

Comment: it does not work like that. You need to use hooks provided by prestashop to hook you module to the checkout carrier section. and when it comes to checkout, distance between warehouse and user home address is calculated with associated cost. I managed to do that (as always ;). I have submitted that as answer too. )